# References that says a proselyte becomes born a new through circumcision: Born again

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

I came across the following excerpt:

> It must be noted that, according to Rabbinic diction, the proselyte,
> by leaving heathenism, became a child again, or was born anew, because
> by the rite of circumcision he disowned his relations and became a son
> of Abraham. (Jebamoth f. lxii. 1, xcii. 1, also Maimon. Issure bia
> c.16).

I need references with details of such rabbinic quotes about the new birth of a man.

Comment: I don't think he becomes a child again (in that he isn't responsible for his sins until he lives as a convert for 13 years). He becomes a new man, in a new family, but not a child.

Comment: What is the source for that quote?

Comment: @Yehuda it's from an old book. I am hoping you can search similar quotes about the new birth of a convert using hebrew text or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the sources you are quoting in your question are:

[Talmud Bavli, Yevamot 62a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.62a.9?lang=bi):

> A convert who converts is like a newborn child

[Talmud Bavli, Yevamot 97a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.97b.12?lang=bi):

> A convert who converts is like a newborn child

[Maimonides, Mishneh Torah, Issurei Biah 14:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.14.11?lang=bi):

> When a gentile converts or a servant is freed, he is like a newborn baby.

Comment: Very helpful .thank you. I should've just used the newborn word in my search to find these, https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=a%20convert%20newborn&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

Answer (score 2):

Conversion isn't complete without it:

Yevamos 46b

> א"ר חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן לעולם אינו גר עד שימול ויטבול
>
> Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba said that Rabbi Yoḥanan said: A man is never considered a convert until he is both circumcised and has immersed

and a convert is considered born anew for certain purposes

e.g. ibid 22a

> גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד דמי
>
> the legal status of a convert who just converted is like that of a child just born

As circumcision is a necessary (but insufficient) factor in the conversion process it is unclear how much it contributes (if any) toward a converts born again status

(See e.g. https://asif.co.il/wpfb-file/alon-shevut-175-17-32-pdf/ for the practical halachic parameters of this designation)